# What is the simplest/best way to have adaptive display on any size screen

Tags: c#, uwp, adaptive-design

Good Day,

I want to know how can I achieve this on uwp , you see on the calculator app from windows 10 , the buttons and other controls are resizing and its content:
[image]

How can I do this on xaml using visualstate and relativepanel?

Thanks

Comment: I think the Calc app is only using basic Grid layout. VisualState is used to transition between different states like landscape view and portrait view, RelativePanel is not used for the adaptive layout either.

Comment: Okay , so just make vertical and horizontal alignment stretch and set a max width and height?

Comment: Try to set proportional (the * mark) height/width to each row/column. For the content inside each cell, set the horizontal/vertical alignment as center.

Comment: can you please provide an example ? Thanks

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/dealing-with-percentage-size-in-wpf/

Comment: thank you , but cant mark a comment an answer

Comment: https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/AdaptiveLayoutAnimation also follow this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic Grid layout which position the contents in a tabular pattern. You want the contents to update their positions according to the parent, which can be easily done by using percentage sizing in the row and column definitions.

For the content inside each cell, set the horizontal/vertical alignment as center.

Please find [this example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/dealing-with-percentage-size-in-wpf/).